# How to Generate PDF from various page templates with ReportLab?

Tags: python, pdf, python-2.x, reportlab

I have JSON file with lots of data and four PDF templates for pages. I need to generate single PDF file with all this data ang page templates. Now my code looks like this:

```
    self.line(self.data['sendr'], 10, 250,
              250, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})
    self.line(self.data['list_num'], 10, 450,
              25, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})
    self.line(self.data['send_date'], 10, 250,
              45, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})
    self.line(self.data['delivery_rate_sum_end'], 10, 450,
              450, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})

    self.can.save()
    self.packet.seek(0)

    new_pdf = PdfFileReader(self.packet)
    current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(
        file("{0}/original/blank_103_1.pdf".format(current_folder), "rb"))
    output = PdfFileWriter()

    page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
    page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page)
    print "Page 1 complete"

    # four row page mail part
    for item in range(3, int(self.data['email_count']) - 2, 4):
        self.line(self.data['sends'][item]['rcpn'], 10, 350,
                  250, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})
        self.line(self.data['sends'][item]['mail_count'], 10, 450,
                  250)

        new_pdf2 = PdfFileReader(self.packet)
        existing_pdf2 = PdfFileReader(
            file("{0}/original/blank_103_2.pdf".format(current_folder), "rb"))

        page2 = existing_pdf2.getPage(0)
        page2.mergePage(new_pdf2.getPage(0))
        output.addPage(page2)
        print "Page ", item, " complete"

    # last page part
    self.line(self.data['sendr'], 10, 100,
              25, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})
    self.line(self.data['list_num'], 10, 70,
              45, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})
    self.line(self.data['send_date'], 10, 150,
              45, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})
    self.line(self.data['delivery_rate_sum_end'], 10, 450,
              450, {'min_font': 7, 'max_string': 70})

    new_pdf1 = PdfFileReader(self.packet)
    existing_pdf1 = PdfFileReader(
        file("{0}/original/blank_103_4.pdf".format(current_folder), "rb"))

    page1 = existing_pdf1.getPage(0)
    page1.mergePage(new_pdf1.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page1)
    print "Last page complete"

    filename = int(time.time())
    outputStream = file(
        "{0}/pdf/f103/{1}.pdf".format(current_folder, filename), "wb")
    output.write(outputStream)
    outputStream.close()
```

It generates a single PDF file with all needed templates for pages but on all pages data rendered from the part for the first page. How can I spread data for every page only(some line-for page 1, some data-for page 2,3,..,n, some data-for last page)?

Comment: Based on the code I see here, I would guess that the problem is the way you generate the `new_pdf`'s what does the self.line function do? As you didn't include those function (or a definition of `self`) it is almost impossible to pinpoint the source of your issue..

Comment: Problem solved. I just needed create new canvas for every template page, and in self.line function use specific canvas for a particular block of code.